# How do you diagram a sentence that does not contain a verb?

Tags: diagramming

I am trying to do a structured sentence analysis of Ephesians 1.  Verse one doesn't contain verb.  It's a salutation/greeting.  That should mean it would not be considered a "independent clause" right?
Here it is:

> Paul, an apostle of Jesus Christ by the will of God, to the saints which are at Ephesus, and to the faithful in Christ Jesus.

I'm weak in sentence diagramming or structuring.  Can someone help?

Comment: As far as I know, this would not be considered a complete syntactic sentence.

Comment: From: Paul@apostle.jc, To: saints@ephesus, BCC: all@faithful.jc -- And people are **still** replying all.

Comment: It is an epistolary greeting. It gives the name of the author, a word about him, the names of the addressees, something about them. There is no verb in the original.

Comment: It's not a sentence but a noun phrase, hence no verb.